# Discord bot help command [discord.py]

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am having issues with setting up help command on my bot. I have removed the default help command from

```
bot.remove_command("help")
```

and then used this code to set my custom help:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['h'])
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send('play <songname>' or 'p <songname>' --> Play a song)
    await ctx.send('pause' or 'pp' --> Pause the song)
    await ctx.send('resume' or 'pr' --> Resume the song)
    await ctx.send('looptrack' or 'lt' --> Loops the current song - beta)
    await ctx.send('dc' --> disconnect me from the voice channel)
```

however, I changed the code now to:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['h'])
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("nothing here")
```

Now when user enters help or `h, this is the output:

```
nothing here
'play <songname>' or 'p <songname>' --> Play a song
'pause' or 'pp' --> Pause the song
'resume' or 'pr' --> Resume the song
'looptrack' or 'lt' --> Loops the current song - beta
'dc' --> disconnect me from the voice channe
```

I don't know why the old help is being printed even after removing them from my help function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, but regenerating the bot token worked.